# ReactiveCrudRepository Criteria Query

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc

I want to discuss a bit further the usage of Criteria and ReactiveCrudRepository.

Spring data r2dbc supports [query by example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-r2dbc/issues/372). Which in many cases is too limited. For example, all types other than String are exact-match only.

Navigating the issues of the project, I found an [answer from @jiangtj](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-r2dbc/issues/565#issuecomment-821781637) and managed to elaborate the following piece of code:

```java
public interface UserRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<User, Long>, ReactiveSearchRepository<User> {

}

interface ReactiveSearchRepository<T> {
    Flux<T> findAll(Criteria criteria, Class<T> domainType);

    public Mono<Page<T>> findAll(Criteria criteria, Pageable pageable, Class<T> domainType);
}
```

And then the implementation for `ReactiveSearchRepositoryImpl`:

```java
@AllArgsConstructor
class ReactiveSearchRepositoryImpl<T> implements ReactiveSearchRepository<T> {

    private final R2dbcEntityTemplate r2dbcTemplate;

    public Flux<T> findAll(Criteria criteria, Class<T> domainType) {
        return r2dbcTemplate.select(domainType)
                .matching(query(criteria))
                .all();
    }

    public Mono<Page<T>> findAll(Criteria criteria, Pageable pageable, Class<T> domainType) {
        Mono<List<T>> list = r2dbcTemplate.select(domainType)
                .matching(query(criteria).with(pageable))
                .all()
                .collectList();
        Mono<Long> count = r2dbcTemplate.select(domainType)
                .matching(query(criteria))
                .count();
        return Mono.zip(list, count)
                .map(tuple -> new PageImpl<>(tuple.getT1(), pageable, tuple.getT2()));
    }
}
```

I'm aware of [Oliver Drotbohm's view](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-r2dbc/issues/371#issuecomment-630081500) about `Criteria` as a store-specific type. Although the Fluent API supports it out of the box.

In my personal view, adding `Criteria` to the Reactive Repositories would empower the framework with a new dimension of querying the DB.

Does it make sense?